# Битовые значения полей структуры

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Есть структура, объявление на С которой выглядит так:

```
   struct Strip {
      ULONG InJob: 1
      ULONG Initializing : 1
      ULONG UsingPool : 1
      ULONG UsingPages : 1
      ULONG FormFactor : 1
      ULONG Reserved: 27
   }
```

Как подобные структуры объявляются в Python? Как объявляются обычные структуры, без побитового значения полей, я знаю, например:

```
class Foo(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('a', c_ulong), ('b', c_long)]
```

А вот как с битовыми значениями  - не имею понятия.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под "побитовыми значениями"?

Comment: почитайте о встроенном модуле [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 0):

У [`ctypes.Structure`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._fields_) есть битовые поля.

Для структуры

```cpp
struct Strip {
    unsigned long InJob: 1;
    unsigned long Initializing : 1;
    unsigned long UsingPool : 1;
    unsigned long UsingPages : 1;
    unsigned long FormFactor : 1;
    unsigned long Reserved: 27;
}
```

эквивалентом будет

```py
class Strip(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("InJob", ctypes.c_ulong, 1),
        ("Initializing", ctypes.c_ulong, 1),
        ("UsingPool", ctypes.c_ulong, 1),
        ("UsingPages", ctypes.c_ulong, 1),
        ("FormFactor", ctypes.c_ulong, 1),
        ("Reserved", ctypes.c_ulong, 27),
    ]
```

Вот только битовые поля очень нестабильно работают в python: [они не кросс-платформенные](https://bugs.python.org/issue29753).

Существует встроенный модуль [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html), он очень прост и функционален. Но, к сожалению, не умеет работать с отдельными битам, а только лишь с октетами.

Как альтернативу я использовал простые битовые маски:

```py
class Strip:
    def __init__(self, inputStream):
        raw = struct.unpack("L", inputStream.read(4))
        self.InJob =        (raw & 0b0000000000000001) >> 0
        self.Initializing = (raw & 0b0000000000000010) >> 1
        self.UsingPool =    (raw & 0b0000000000000100) >> 2
        self.UsingPages =   (raw & 0b0000000000001000) >> 3
        self.FormFactor =   (raw & 0b0000000000010000) >> 4
        self.Reserved =     (raw & 0b1111111111100000) >> 5
```

[Вот тут](https://github.com/Teivaz/PNUnpacker/blob/master/io_nebula/ntx.py#L24) можно посмотреть как я использовал этот подход.

P.S. только будьте осторожны с [порядком байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).